# QPushButton when subclassed draws box around icon

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I am trying to customize a QPUshButton by subclassing it and overriding the paintEvent. I am writing the text, followed by the icon as below:

```
paintEvent(QPaintEvent *paint)
    {
         QStyleOption opt;
         opt.init(this);
         QPainter p(this);
        //Draw the base
         style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);

        //Draw the text
         style()->drawItemText(&p,this->rect(),Qt::AlignCenter,(this->palette()), true, this->text());

         if(!this->icon().isNull())
            //Draw the icon at 75% button height
            style()->drawItemPixmap(&p, this->rect(),Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignVCenter, this->icon().pixmap(this->rect().height()  * 0.75));

    }
```

However, the button I get is as below:

[image]

If you can see, there is a box around the icon image. How do I remove that? (The icon size appears bigger because I took the snapshot before I reduced the size. However, the box appears even if the image is much smaller and fits into the image).

Comment: Have you tried setting `p.setPen( Qt::NoPen )`?  `QPainter` defaults to using a cosmetic black pen - though I don't know why it's just affecting the pixmap.

Comment: @cmannett85 Just tried it - does not help. the box is still there.

Comment: Maybe it's because your icon is in wrong format? It should be something which can handle with masks like *.png or *.ico

Comment: @Blood. Yes - the issue was with the image. I figured out that there was a one pixel line around the image. It was not visible until I put it on a gray background.

Comment: I've seen a similar problem where the image being drawn had focus and thus was causing the extra shadow/box.